# Blocked by cors policy when image upload to cloudinary

Tags: node.js, reactjs, upload, cors, cloudinary

I got a error like this : " Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://.../api/upload/' from origin 'http://..' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. " when i upload image in cloudinary

This is my front end :

```
`import axios from "axios";
import { base_url } from "../../utils/base_url";
import { config } from "../../utils/axiosconfig";

const uploadImg = async (data) => {
    const response = await axios.post(`${base_url}upload/`, data, config)
    return response.data
}

const uploadService = {
    uploadImg
}

export default uploadService`
```

Backend (Cloudinary) :

```
`const cloudinary = require('cloudinary')
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY
})

const cloudinaryUploadImg = async (fileToUpload) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileToUpload, (result) => {
            resolve({
                url: result.secure_url,
                asset_id: result.asset_id,
                public_id: result.public_id
            }, {
                resource_type: "auto"
            })
        })
    })
}

module.exports = { cloudinaryUploadImg }`
```

Backend (Controller) :

```
`const fs = require('fs')
const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler')
const { cloudinaryUploadImg } = require('../utils/cloudinary')

const uploadImages = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const uploader = (path) => cloudinaryUploadImg(path, "images")
        const urls = []
        const files = req.files
        for (const file of files) {
            const { path } = file
            const newPath = await uploader(path)
            urls.push(newPath)
            fs.unlinkSync(path)
        }
        const images = urls.map((file) => { return file })
        res.json(images)
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error)
    }
})

module.exports = {
    uploadImages
}`
```

Comment: When uploading files using Cloudinary SDK, the upload method supports different file source formats as [described in this document](https://community.cloudinary.com/home/leaving?allowTrusted=1&target=https%3A%2F%2Fcloudinary.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fimage_upload_api_reference%23upload_required_parameters). There is a possibility that the files are not accessible on the server environment through the PATH variable that you are using in your code (i.e., you could try using another format to verify).

Comment: How could i change this code